# Retrieving Puma stats programatically showing blank results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

im trying to retrieve Puma statistics by calling `Puma.stats` in my Rails controllers although im seeing essentially empty results.

I logged out the contents of Puma.stats during a normal request and I get the following results

```
{:started_at=>"2019-09-11T04:31:06Z", :workers=>0, :phase=>0, :booted_workers=>0, :old_workers=>0, :worker_status=>[]}
```

I know this is wrong however, when I run the Puma control app (using activate_control_app in Puma.rb) and hit /stats?token=blah I see

```
"workers": 4,
"phase": 0,
"booted_workers": 4,
"old_workers": 0,
"worker_status": [
{
"started_at": "2019-09-11T04:32:49Z",
"pid": 60797,
"index": 0,
"phase": 0,
"booted": true,
"last_checkin": "2019-09-11T04:39:04Z",
"last_status": {
"backlog": 0,
"running": 1,
"pool_capacity": 10,
"max_threads": 10
}
},
...... etc etc
```

Am I missing something here? Is there any reason why I cannot see any stats by simply calling `Puma.stats` in my controller? Tried in both dev and production modes just incase.

Using Puma 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason why I cannot see any stats by simply calling Puma.stats in my controller?

Yes, only the master process has reasonable `Puma.stats`, and your controller lives in a worker process. This got addressed a little:

https://github.com/puma/puma/commit/3ce98b7960b0f5737a5799c72021b08f3317b01f

For the usual cluster mode puma, you can have the master start a thread e.g. from the `before_fork` hook. This is where `Puma.stats` returns reasonable data. Pass it whereever you want (e.g. write it to a file). Google for `"puts Puma.stats"` for example code.

Alternatively, you can access the stats from the control server, if you opt-in to start it: `http://127.0.0.1/stats?token=...`.